# Writing to stream and then creating a new stream

Tags: c#

Suppose you have this:

```
using FileStream fileStream = ...;
fileStream.Write(bytes);

using GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
gzipStream.Write(bytesToCompress);
```

Would writing to `fileStream` first, and then creating a new `GZipStream` from that stream and then writing bytes to it work?

Do I have to flush `fileStream` first? Or is this simply unsafe?

Comment: In this case the file should end up with "bytes" followed by the gzipped compressed data. Did you try it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah ok. That should be good. I haven't tested it yet though

Comment: GZipStream will write to the underlying stream, fileStream in this case, and just append more bytes after the ones that were written by `.Write(bytes)`.

Comment: _"I haven't tested it yet though"_ -- Stack Overflow isn't a "guess what my code will do" site. It's for providing answers to _genuine_ practical problems related to programming. If after you've actually _tested_ your code, you have some _specific problem_ that you can present a well-written question about, feel free to post about that. There's no useful question here at the moment. Please read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Would writing to fileStream first, and then creating a new GZipStream from that stream and then writing bytes to it work?

Yes, that is sort of the point of streams really, that they are chainable. See [Compose streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/composing-streams).

> Do I have to flush fileStream first? Or is this simply unsafe?

Flush is only necessary when you wish to purge buffers and guarantee that the data are written to the backing store (e.g. the filesystem or network).